# I'm trying to update pyqtgraph plot by adding new data on existing record

Tags: python, pyqtgraph

'''
I'm just checking how pyqtgraph works on timeseries data
'''
import sys
from PyQt6 import QtWidgets, QtCore
import pyqtgraph as pg  # import PyQtGraph after Qt
import datetime as dt
from commonFunction import separation
import pandas as pd

```
class TimeAxisItem(pg.AxisItem):
    def tickStrings(self, values, scale, spacing):
        return [
            dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(value).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
            for value in values
        ]


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        dataaxis = TimeAxisItem(orientation="bottom")
        self.graphWidget = pg.PlotWidget(axisItems={"bottom": dataaxis})
        self.setCentralWidget(self.graphWidget)
        data=pandas.readcsv(#any company's stock value)
        self.x, self.y = separation(data) #this will return stock value and date
       
        self.graphWidget.setBackground("w")
        pen = pg.mkPen(color=(255, 0, 0))
        print(type(self.x))
        print(type(self.y))
        self.data_line = self.graphWidget.plot(self.x, self.y, pen=pen)

       
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.setInterval(1000)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(lambda: self.update_plot_data(data.tail(1))) #this will add last value of the data csv 
        self.timer.start()

    def update_plot_data(self, newValue):
        x, y = self.data_line.getData()
        x = x.tolist()
        y = y.tolist()
        
        new_x, new_y = separation(newValue)
        x.append(new_x)
        y.append(new_y)

        self.data_line.setData(x, y)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: no worries i solved the problem . i was updating plot with same values that's why it looks like graph is not updating but actually it was updating on same point.

Answer (score 0):

Actually i'm dumb i was plotling on same date and wondering why it's no updating.